# PHP Timestamp into DateTime

Tags: php, date, datetime, date-format, time-format

Do you know how I can convert this to a strtotime, or a similar type  of value to pass into the **DateTime** object?

The date I have:

```
Mon, 12 Dec 2011 21:17:52 +0000
```

What I've tried:

```
$time = substr($item->pubDate, -14);
$date = substr($item->pubDate, 0, strlen($time));

$dtm = new DateTime(strtotime($time));
$dtm->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone(ADMIN_TIMEZONE));
$date = $dtm->format('D, M dS');
$time = $dtm->format('g:i a');
```

The above is not correct. If I loop through a lot of different dates its all the same date.

Answer (score 223, accepted):

You don't need to turn the string into a timestamp in order to create the `DateTime` object (in fact, its constructor doesn't even allow you to do this, as you can tell).  You can simply feed your date string into the `DateTime` constructor as-is:

```
// Assuming $item->pubDate is "Mon, 12 Dec 2011 21:17:52 +0000"
$dt = new DateTime($item->pubDate);
```

That being said, if you do have a timestamp that you wish to use instead of a string, you can do so using [`DateTime::setTimestamp()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.settimestamp.php):

```
$timestamp = strtotime('Mon, 12 Dec 2011 21:17:52 +0000');
$dt = new DateTime();
$dt->setTimestamp($timestamp);
```

**Edit (2014-05-07):**

I actually wasn't aware of this at the time, but the `DateTime` constructor *does* support creating instances directly from timestamps.  According to [this documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.compound.php), all you need to do is prepend the timestamp with an `@` character:

```
$timestamp = strtotime('Mon, 12 Dec 2011 21:17:52 +0000');
$dt = new DateTime('@' . $timestamp);
```

Comment: This works great. I had tried this previously but must have not given it enough of a chance!!! thanks :))

Comment: Note that `new DateTime('@' . $timestamp)`  and `$dt = new DateTime();
$dt->setTimestamp($timestamp)` don't deal with timezones the same way. See my answer @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12038558/php-timestamp-into-datetime/35525866#35525866 for more details.

Comment: I think `new DateTime("@$timestamp")` may be more readable.

Comment: A little shorter: `$date = (new DateTime)->setTimestamp($timestamp);`

Answer (score 66):

While [@drrcknlsn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/915064/drrcknlsn) is correct to assert there are multiple ways to convert a time string to a datatime, it's important to realize that these different ways don't deal with timezones in the same way.

---

#### Option 1 : `DateTime('@' . $timestamp)`

Consider the following code :

```
date_format(date_create('@'. strtotime('Mon, 12 Dec 2011 21:17:52 +0800')), 'c');
```

The `strtotime` bit eliminates the time zone information, and the `date_create` function assumes GMT.

As such, the output will be the following, no matter which server I run it on :

```
2011-12-12T13:17:52+00:00
```

---

#### Option 2 : `date_create()->setTimestamp($timestamp)`

Consider the following code :

```
date_format(date_create()->setTimestamp(strtotime('Mon, 12 Dec 2011 21:17:52 +0800')), 'c');
```

You might expect this to produce the same output. However, if I execute this code from a Belgian server, I get the following output :

```
2011-12-12T14:17:52+01:00
```

Unlike the `date_create` function, the `setTimestamp` method assumes the time zone of the server (CET in my case) rather than GMT.

---

#### Explicitly setting your time zone

If you want to make sure your output matches the time zone of your input, it's best to set it explicitly.

Consider the following code :

```
date_format(date_create('@'. strtotime('Mon, 12 Dec 2011 21:17:52 +0800'))->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Asia/Hong_Kong')), 'c')
```

Now, also consider the following code :

```
date_format(date_create()->setTimestamp(strtotime('Mon, 12 Dec 2011 21:17:52 +0800'))->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Asia/Hong_Kong')), 'c')
```

Because we explicitly set the time zone of the output to match that of the input, both will create the same (correct) output :

```
2011-12-12T21:17:52+08:00
```

Answer (score 56):

Probably the simplest solution is just:

```
DateTime::createFromFormat('U', $timeStamp);
```

Where 'U' means Unix epoch. See docs: http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php

Comment: This method also ignores timezone

Comment: @BoukeVersteegh and which one doesn't?

Comment: @BoukeVersteegh This is a Unix timestamp!, **it frees you from timezones  problems while creating the object**. just use `->setTimezone` to set the preferable timezone before calling `->format()`

Comment: @BoukeVersteegh Check this big note from the [PHP manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php) **"The $timezone parameter and the current timezone are ignored when the $time parameter either is a UNIX timestamp (e.g. @946684800) or specifies a timezone (e.g. 2010-01-28T15:00:00+02:00). "**

Comment: Unix timestamps don't have timezones, they are always UTC by definition

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution:

```php
function changeDateTimezone($date, $from='UTC', $to='Asia/Tehran', $targetFormat="Y-m-d H:i:s") {
    $date = new DateTime($date, new DateTimeZone($from));
    $date->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone($to));
    return $date->format($targetFormat);
}
```